# Remove a particular character from varchar while retrieving data using query

Tags: sql

I want to remove a particular character while retrieving a varchar from a table. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT ServiceName,
       case isNumeric(Ramusage) 
         when 1 then 
           cast ( ltrim ( rtrim ( ramusage )) as int )
         else 
           0 
       end as test,
       priority
  FROM ProcessInfo
```

Here the problem is `ramusage` is a `varchar` and it stores values like 12,500K, 4,321K.

Here I want to remove the "K" from the entry and display the number alone.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the REPLACE function:

```
REPLACE(ramusage, 'k', '')
```

Reference:

- [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)
- [Oracle](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php)
- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Answer (score 2):

Use REPLACE

```
DECLARE @ProcessInfo TABLE(
        ServiceName VARCHAR(MAX),
        Ramusage VARCHAR(MAX),
        priority INT
)

INSERT INTO @ProcessInfo (ServiceName,Ramusage,priority)
SELECT 'TEST','12,123K',1

SELECT ServiceName,
       case isNumeric(REPLACE(REPLACE(Ramusage,'K',''),',','')) 
         when 1 then 
           cast ( ltrim ( rtrim ( REPLACE(REPLACE(Ramusage,'K',''),',',''))) as int )
         else 
           0 
       end as test,
       priority
  FROM @ProcessInfo
```

what we have done is to create a CLR function to take a string amd remove all non numeric items

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString RemoveNonNumeric(SqlString strValue)
    {
        string strNew = strValue.ToString();

        char[] chrArray = strNew.ToCharArray();

        strNew = null;

        for (int iChar = 0; iChar < chrArray.Length; iChar++)
        {
            if (Char.IsNumber(chrArray[iChar]))
                strNew += chrArray[iChar];
        }

        // Put your code here
        return new SqlString(strNew);
    }
```

Comment: If dealing with SQL Server 2005+, I'd do the REPLACE stuff in a CTE.

Comment: we have played around alot with a couple of ideas, one of our transaction tables have a foreign transaction ref, and testing with just over 4 mil records, we found that the clr function was the fastest.. (also sql server 2005)

Answer (score 0):

```
substr( ltrim( rtrim( ramusage ) ), length( ramusage ) - 1)
```

**edit:** `replace`, as mentioned in the other answers, is probably better.